# How to implement a service that will wait for GPS signal

Tags: android, gps

I want to implement a service that will show the loading screen till the GPS dont find location in it. After some time it shows alert and return the place last known location or the basic cord (0.0). Unfortunatly the first read is null and it stays like this no matter if the GPS is on or off.

 
**GPS HANDLER**

```
public class GPSLocation implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        GPSStatusReceiver.GpsStatusChangeListener{
    public static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
    public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    private static final int PERMISSION_GRANTED = 0;
    private static final int PERMISSION_DENIED = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_BLOCKED = 2;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private LocationCallback mCallback;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GPSStatusReceiver mGPSStatusReceiver;

    private long intervalMillis = 10000;
    private long fastestIntervalMillis = 5000;
    private int accuracy = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;

    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private boolean isLocationEnabled = false;
    private boolean isPermissionLocked = false;

    public GPSLocation(Activity activity, LocationCallback callback) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
        mCallback = callback;
        //creating new client Api
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

            createLocationRequest();
        mGPSStatusReceiver = new GPSStatusReceiver(mContext, this);
    }


    public void init(){
        isInitialized = true;
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                requestPermission();
            } else {
                connect();
            }
        }
    }


    public void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(intervalMillis);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestIntervalMillis);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(accuracy);
    }


    public LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        return mLocationRequest;
    }


    public void connect(){
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null && isInitialized) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


    public void disconnect(){
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null && isInitialized) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    private void getLastKnownLocation(){
        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.i(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation restart ");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else {
            if (checkLocationPermission(mContext) && isLocationEnabled) {
                Log.i(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation read ");

                 if(mCurrentLocation==null){
                     mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mCallback.onLastKnowLocationFetch(mCurrentLocation);
                     Log.i(TAG,"mCurrentLocation is "+mCurrentLocation);
                }
                startLocationUpdates();
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation get permission ");
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "mCurrentLocation " + mCurrentLocation);
    }


    public void startLocationUpdates() {
        if(checkLocationPermission(mContext)
                && mGoogleApiClient != null
                && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()
                && isLocationEnabled) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }


    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null
                && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (checkLocationPermission(mContext) && isLocationEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation read ");
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
            }
            if(mCurrentLocation == null ) {
                mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                mCallback.onLastKnowLocationFetch(mCurrentLocation);
            }
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
        mCallback.onLocationUpdate(mCurrentLocation);
        requestPermission();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged : " + location);
       if(location!=null)
        mCallback.onLocationUpdate(location);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChange() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onGpsStatusChange");
        if(isInitialized && !isPermissionLocked) {
            if (!isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
                isLocationEnabled = false;
                isPermissionLocked = true;
                stopLocationUpdates();
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }


    private void requestPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            String[] appPerm = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, appPerm, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            getLocationSetting();
        }
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GPSLocation.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getLastKnownLocation();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCallback.onLocationSettingsError();
            }
        }
    }


    private void getLocationSetting(){
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder =
                new LocationSettingsRequest
                        .Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        Log.i(TAG, "SUCCESS");
                        isLocationEnabled = true;
                        isPermissionLocked = false;
                        getLastKnownLocation();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "RESOLUTION_REQUIRED");
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    mActivity,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            mCallback.onLocationSettingsError();
                        }finally {
                            isPermissionLocked = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE");
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mCallback.onLocationSettingsError();
                        isPermissionLocked = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        int permState;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                mActivity,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                            permState = PERMISSION_BLOCKED;
                        }else{permState = PERMISSION_DENIED;}
                    }else {permState = PERMISSION_GRANTED;}
                }
                else{permState = PERMISSION_DENIED;}

                switch (permState){
                    case PERMISSION_BLOCKED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Please give gps location permission to use the app.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(mContext);
                        mCallback.onLocationPermissionDenied();
                        break;
                    case PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Permission Denied, app cannot access the gps location.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case PERMISSION_GRANTED:
                        getLocationSetting();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gpsEnabled = false;
        boolean networkEnabled = false;

        try {
            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {}

        try {
            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {}

        return gpsEnabled && networkEnabled;
    }

    public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        final Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public static boolean checkLocationPermission(Context context) {
        String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
        int res = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    public interface LocationCallback {
        void onLastKnowLocationFetch(Location location);
        void onLocationUpdate(Location location);
        void onLocationPermissionDenied();
        void onLocationSettingsError();
    }
    public void close() {
        mGPSStatusReceiver.unRegisterReceiver();
    }}
```

**Recivier Class**

```
public class GPSStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private GpsStatusChangeListener mCallback;
private Context mContext;
public GPSStatusReceiver(Context context, GpsStatusChangeListener callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
    mContext = context;

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    context.registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);
}

public void unRegisterReceiver(){
    Log.i(TAG, "unRegisterReceiver");
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(this);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
        Log.i(TAG, "in PROVIDERS_CHANGED");
        mCallback.onGpsStatusChange();
    }
}

public interface GpsStatusChangeListener{
    void onGpsStatusChange();
}}
```

**Activity Class**

```
public class LocationFinder extends AppCompatActivity  implements GPSLocation.LocationCallback,OnMapReadyCallback {

    Log log;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button confirmLocalizationButton;
    private GPSLocation mGPSLocation;
    private LatLng currentPosition= new LatLng(0,0);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mGPSLocation = new GPSLocation(this, this);
        mGPSLocation.init();
        mapInit();
        buttonInit();
        checkInternetStatus();
    }

    private void buttonInit() {
        confirmLocalizationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirm_location);
        confirmLocalizationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentPosition=markerOptions.getPosition();
                log.i(TAG,"currentPosition:: "+currentPosition);
                Intent i = new Intent(LocationFinder.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("coordinates",currentPosition);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLastKnowLocationFetch(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLastKnowLocationFetch " + location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdate(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLocationUpdate " + location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationPermissionDenied() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationSettingsError() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        mGPSLocation.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGPSLocation.startLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGPSLocation.stopLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGPSLocation.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mGPSLocation.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == GPSLocation.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            mGPSLocation.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GPSLocation.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            mGPSLocation.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 1);
        mMap.moveCamera(camera);

        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(currentPosition);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(mMap.getCameraPosition().target);
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        });
    }
    private void mapInit(){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void checkInternetStatus(){
        if(!InternetConnection.getConnectivityStatus(this)) {
            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Turn on your network service to enjoy full functionality of this application  ")
                    .setCancelable(true).
                    setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Ive made function that will wait for GPS signal but still does make a connection

```
   private void waitForGPSSignal(){
    progressWindow();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           getLastKnownLocation();

          if(mCurrentLocation!=null)
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
ProgressDialog progress;
private void progressWindow() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progress.setMessage("waiting");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    if (mContext != null) {
        progress.show();
    }}
```

I called it for GPSLocation in here:

```
 result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "SUCCESS");
                    isLocationEnabled = true;
                    isPermissionLocked = false;
                    waitForGPSSignal();
                    getLastKnownLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "RESOLUTION_REQUIRED");
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                mActivity,
                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        mCallback.onLocationSettingsError();
                    }finally {
                        isPermissionLocked = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mCallback.onLocationSettingsError();
                    isPermissionLocked = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

And Im still obtain null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

```
if (Utility.isLocationEnabled(Splash_Activity.this)) {
    new FetchCordinates.execute();
} else {
    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
}
```

**FetchCordinates.java**

```
public class FetchCordinates extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public VeggsterLocationListener mVeggsterLocationListener;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(InitialRegistration.this, "",
                "Fetching Location");
        mVeggsterLocationListener = new VeggsterLocationListener();
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mVeggsterLocationListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        System.out.println("Cancelled by user!");
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mVeggsterLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Log.e("AsynckLL", "LATITUDE :" + mLatitude + " LONGITUDE :"
        // + mLongitude);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        // do your logic

        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mVeggsterLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        while (mLatitude == 0.0) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class VeggsterLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Log.e("OnProviderDisabled", "OnProviderDisabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Log.e("onProviderEnabled", "onProviderEnabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // Log.e("onStatusChanged", "onStatusChanged");
        }
    }
}
```

if Location is not enabled.

```
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Splash_Activity.this);
    builder.setMessage(
            "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                final int id) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                                    100);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                        final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

and inside `onActivityResults`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (Utility.isLocationEnabled(Splash_Activity.this)) {
            new FetchCordinates().execute();
        } else {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Off", 1000)
                .show();
    }
}
```

This is not service as you mentioned in your question. but i hope somehow it will help you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Should I add new FetchCordinates().execute(); in part of result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>()  ( actually in case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS)?    

 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mVeggsterLocationListener); in FetchCoordinate cast permission exception  and how about mLongitude,and mLatitude. Should I return it to the GPSLocation class?  Im not really good with this :/